# TypedArray vs. Array in AssemblyScript

Tags: assemblyscript

What are some scenarios where you would choose one over the other when programming in AssemblyScript?

In my case I am trying to build a K-d tree from a list of tuples of floating point numbers. Because I need to rearrange and sort the incoming list of tuples, my first go-to is using `Array<Array<f64>>` since I can easily add and remove data from it.[

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct, the standard array is the most flexible.

In Assemblyscript there are three array types.

### [Array](https://www.assemblyscript.org/stdlib/array.html)

`let a:f32[] = [0,1,2]`

- Resizable
- Can hold references
- The least performant

### [Static Array](https://www.assemblyscript.org/stdlib/staticarray.html)

`let a:StaticArray<f32> = [0,1,2]`

- Fixed size
- Can hold references
- Great performance

### [Typed Array](https://www.assemblyscript.org/stdlib/typedarray.html)

`let a:Float32Array = new Float32Array(3)`

- Fixed size
- Can hold numeric values only
- Great performance
- Buffer access for shared views etc

Note - it is not currently possible to initialize a typed array with values, ie

`new Float32Array([0,1,2])`